# Idiomatic way of only selecting certain rows from a dataframe (whose index exists in other dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two pandas timeseries, and the indexes on both are timestamps. The thing is - not all of the timestamps exist on both timeseries. I want to perform a linear regression on the points that are matched up, ignoring those which have no 'pair'

This is my current solution, but it seems somewhat verbose and ugly:

```
indexes_used = sorted(list(set(series1).intersection(series2)))

perform_regression(series1.loc[indexes_used], series2.loc[indexes_used])
```

Alternatively, I was thinking of doing (but creating a temporary dataframe seems redundant):

```
temp_frame = pd.concat([series1, series2]).T.dropna() #need the transpose to keep timestamps on vertical axis

perform_regression(blabla)
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Can you just `pd.merge(..., how='inner')`?

Comment: Trying to merge two timeseries gives me the error that the Series have no columns. And merging them still doesn't solve the main problem that I had. (Selecting the right indices)

Comment: Merging should work. You need inner join, right? 
Try `series1.to_frame().join(series2)`

Comment: @Happy001, that is giving me a value error that "the other series must have a name". HYRY's solution works well though.

Comment: @James, that's because your series don't have names. You can set them like `series2.name='b'`. But if you prefer two separate series, @HYRY's sol is excellent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `Series.align`:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
b = pd.Series([49, 54, 62, 74], index=[2, 6, 4, 0])

a2, b2 = a.align(b, join="inner")
```

the output:

```
2    5
4    7
dtype: int64

2    49
4    62
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yep, this works! Thanks! (It's also much cleaner than what I had).